# Convert and filter array of objects to one object

Tags: javascript

I have next array of objects:

```
const fields = [
    { givenName: 'firstName' },
    { familyName: 'lastName' },
    { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
    { 'custom:data2': '' },
    { 'custom:data3': null },
  ];
```

What I need is to filter out elements which is empty, null or undefined and convert it to one object pameters:

```
{  
   givenName: 'firstName',
   familyName: 'lastName',
   'custom:data': 'blabla'
}
```

Comment: May the objects have more than one keys?

Comment: nope, only one.

Comment: You have explicitly said to exclude `null`, `undefined` and `''` (empty) meaning you want to keep everything else. Most answers including the one you have accepted don't do that. Most rely on truthy/falsy checks excluding values such as `0`, `false` and `NaN`. (FYI)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could filter the array by looking to the values. This approach assumes, that only one key/value pair is available.

```js
const
    fields = [{ givenName: 'firstName' }, { familyName: 'lastName' }, { 'custom:data': 'blabla' }, { 'custom:data2': '' }, { 'custom:data3': null }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...fields.filter(o => {
        const [v] = Object.values(o);
        return v || v === 0 || v === false;
    }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

### How to check whether a value is empty?

Most people would go about this with a truthy check:

```js
const empty = x => x ? false : true;

empty(null);      //=> true
empty(undefined); //=> true
empty('');        //=> true
```

But that's *always* going to exclude things you perhaps didn't intend to exclude:

```js
empty(0);         //=> true
empty(false);     //=> true
empty(NaN);       //=> true
```

*Admittedly `NaN` could be seen as the "empty" value of its type but for the sake of your question and educational purpose we'll say it's not.*

The "workaround" is often something like that:

```js
const empty = x => (x || x === 0 || x === false || Number.isNaN(x)) ? false : true;
```

However this doesn't need to be more complicated than this:

```js
const empty = x => x == null || x === '' ? true : false;
```

Checking for either `undefined` or `null` is one example where not using triple equality makes sense:

```js
null == undefined;
// true
null === undefined;
// false
```

See [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-equality-checks).

If you need to exclude `null`, `undefined` and `''` please don't rely on clever shorthand tricks and just be explicit about it. Type checking should be a straightforward job (YMMV) and not a show-off contest. Future you and your team mates will thank you.

As for your question, I'd suggest this:

Merge everything you've got with `Object.assign`:

```js
Object.assign({}, {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:2});
// {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Then deconstruct it into pairs, exclude those whose value is empty, then reconstruct the object from what's left:

```js
const merge = xs =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(
      Object.assign({}, ...xs))
        .filter(([_, v]) =>
          v != null && v !== ''));
        
        
console.log(merge(fields));
```

```html
<script>
const fields = [
  { givenName: 'firstName' },
  { familyName: 'lastName' },
  { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
  { 'custom:data2': '' },
  { 'custom:data3': null },
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce` and `forEach` and check if value of each property is falsy or not.

```js
const fields = [
  { givenName: 'firstName' },
  { familyName: 'lastName' },
  { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
  { 'custom:data2': '' },
  { 'custom:data3': null },
];

const result = fields.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v || [false, 0].includes(v)) r[k] = v
  })

  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const fields = [
    { givenName: 'firstName' },
    { familyName: 'lastName' },
    { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
    { 'custom:data2': '' },
    { 'custom:data3': null },
  ];
  
 res = fields.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur[Object.keys(cur)[0]]) {
       acc = { ...acc, ...cur }
    }
    return acc
 }, {})
 
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: This excludes valid values such as `0` and `false`

Answer (score 3):

```js
const fields = [
  { givenName: 'firstName' },
  { familyName: 'lastName' },
  { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
  { 'custom:data2': '' },
  { 'custom:data3': null },
];

const result = fields.reduce( ( acc, field ) => {
  Object.keys( field ).forEach( ( key ) => {
    if( field[key] ) {
      acc[key] = field[key];
    }
  } )
  return acc;
}, {} )
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` method to filter out the `empty`, `null` or `undefined` objects. Then using `Array.prototype.map()` make a `key-value` pair array. At last, use `Object.fromEntries()` method to transform it to a single object.

```js
const fields = [
  { givenName: 'firstName' },
  { familyName: 'lastName' },
  { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
  { 'custom:data2': '' },
  { 'custom:data3': null },
];
const ret = Object.fromEntries(
  fields
    .filter((x) => {
      const value = Object.values(x)[0];
      return value || value === false || value === 0 || Object.is(value, NaN);
    })
    .map((x) => [Object.keys(x)[0], Object.values(x)[0]])
);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: @customcommander that's actually a good point he explicitly wrote that. I think nobody took this into concideration.

Comment: @customcommander Btw, almost all other posted answers suffer from this problem...

Comment: Today I learned something: I knew `NaN === NaN` is false but I didn't know that `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you.

```js
const fields = [
    { givenName: 'firstName' },
    { familyName: 'lastName' },
    { 'custom:data': 'blabla' },
    { 'custom:data2': '' },
    { 'custom:data3': null },
  ];
  
 let item = {};

for ( let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ ){
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fields[i])) {
   if ( value !== null && value !== '' )
      item [key] = value;
  }
 
}

 console.log(item);
```

Comment: You will let `undefined` through

Comment: when you run the code in snippet it seems working.

Answer (score 0):

Works with one key, simple modification can work on `n` keys.

```js
const fields = [
    { givenName: "firstName" },
    { familyName: "lastName" },
    { "custom:data": "blabla" },
    { "custom:data2": "" },
    { "custom:data3": null },
];

const reduced = fields
    .filter((f) => {
        const key = Object.keys(f)[0];
        return f[key] === "" || f[key] === null || f[key] === undefined
            ? false
            : true;
    })
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const key = Object.keys(curr)[0];
        acc[key] = curr[key];
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(reduced);
```